# Why does my code print a value that I have not assigned as yet?

Tags: python

I'm in the process of learning python and I'm a little confused about how my function is running.
I declared a function but I did not assign a value to said function until a couple lines later, however, I had asked for the value before. 
To my understanding python runs code line by line, similar to c, so why does it still give the value? Sorry if the question I asked is a little confusing, I included my code so you'll see what I'm trying to ask.
As you can see I'm asking for a value in lines 2 and 3, however I declared the values till in 7. Why do lines 2 - 3 give the values I declared ?

```py
def cheese_and_crackers(cheese_count, box_of_crackers):
    print(f"You have {cheese_count} cheeses!")
    print(f"You have {box_of_crackers} boxes of crackers")
    print("Man that's enough for a party!")
    print("Get a blanket \n")

print("We can just give the function numbers directly")
cheese_and_crackers(20, 32)

print("OR, we can use variables from our script")
amount_of_cheese = 10
amount_of_crackers = 32

cheese_and_crackers(amount_of_cheese, amount_of_crackers)
```

Comment: Your function is executed only when it's called. Because you referred to 'c', I believe you know 'c'. It's same as you do in 'c'.

Comment: The variable names outside the `def` are completely unrelated to the variable names in the `def` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines in a Python program can be executed in a different order than their placement in the program. What happens when a line is "executed" may differ from what you expect. Given that, let's look at your program as it is executed, leaving out some of the finer points. You can see what I explain by running the program one line at a time in a debugger (a standalone one or one that is included in your IDE such as Spyder or Visual Studio Code).

Before the execution begins, the code is "compiled" into a version that is easier for the computer to handle. Then execution begins with line 1.

**Your line 1 is a `def` statement. Executing this line does not execute the function**. Instead, the code lines for the function are placed into memory, and the name of function (in your case `cheese_and_crackers`) is given to that collection of lines. Then the lines inside the function are skipped and execution continues with the line after the function (in your case, line 6). If you run the debugger you will see that execution jumps from line 1 to line 6.

Line 6 is straightforward: some text is printed to standard output.

Line 7 sees the name `cheese_and_crackers` with a left parenthesis following, so Python knows to execute (finally) the function that was previously defined in line 1. Python calculates the arguments `20` and `32`, assigns them to the names `cheese_count` and `box_of_crackers`, notes that those names are for the inside of the function, does some other things I'll skip over, then goes to line 2.

Line 2 sees that it needs the value of name `cheese_count` and looks to see if that name exists in the function. It does--it was assigned `20` in line 7--so that value is used.

Lines 3 through 5 are done similarly.

When finishing line 5, Python sees the function is finished. The names that were created for this function execution, namely `cheese_count` and `box_of_crackers`, are destroyed and their values marked for possible destruction. Then execution resumes after the line that called the function.

Line 8 is straightforward.

Lines 9 and 10 define new variables. The values are calculated, stored in memory, and given the names `amount_of_cheese` and `amount_of_crackers`. Since these lines are not inside a function, those names are marked as being "global".

Line 11 is like line 7, so the values of the parameters are calculated and stored in the variables `cheese_count` and `box_of_crackers`.

Lines 2 through 5 are executed (again) but the *current* values of the names are used.

When done, execution resume to after line 11. Since there is nothing after line 11, the program ends.

Is all that clear? **In summary, you are correct that "Python runs code line by line," but not always in top-to-bottom order. In particular, lines 2 and 3 are executed *after* line 7 then again after lines 9-11.**

Comment: Thank you so much for this, really helped me in understanding this concept more clearly!